# Finding $\lambda$ for which $\alpha=i$ is a root of $z^2+\lambda z-4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, quadratics

(Note: $i$ refers to the imaginary unit)

> I am trying to find the values of $\lambda$ for which $\alpha =i$ is a root of the quadratic:
> $$z^2+\lambda z-4$$

Using the quadratic formula I got:
$$z=\frac{-\lambda \pm \sqrt{\lambda^2+16}}{2}$$

(Note: I believe that $\alpha$ refers to the root that is equal to $\frac{-b \textbf{+} \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$, but I could be mistaken)

Therefore, to find the value of $\lambda$ for which $\alpha =i$, I have to solve the equation:

$$ i=\frac{-\lambda + \sqrt{\lambda^2+16}}{2}$$

Here is an outline of the steps I took:

Multiply both sides by $2$ and add $\lambda$ to both sides:
$$2i+\lambda=\sqrt{\lambda^2 +16}$$
Square both sides:
$$4i^2 +4\lambda i +\lambda^2 =\lambda^2 +16$$
Subtract $\lambda^2$ from both sides then solve for $\lambda$:
$$\lambda=-5i$$

However, $\lambda=-5i$ does not solve the equation ($ i \neq 4i$ ), which is very confusing. Where did I go wrong?

P.S: I did find that $ \lambda=-5i $ was a solution to the other root, $i=\frac{-\lambda - \sqrt{\lambda^2+16}}{2}$.

Comment: if $i$ is a root doesn't it mean that $i^2+i\lambda -4=0$,$\lambda=-5i$

Comment: Yes, that's part of the problem. Then why doesn't $i=\frac{-\lambda + \sqrt{\lambda^2+16}}{2}$ work when you substitute $\lambda=-5i$?

Comment: It does? $$i=\frac{-\lambda - \sqrt{\lambda^2+16}}{2}=i=\frac{5i - \sqrt{-25+16}}{2}=\frac{2i}{2}=i$$
It's just one of the two roots

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that at the end of my post. What I don't understand is why $ i \neq \frac{-(5i)+ \sqrt{(-5i)^2+16}}{2}=4i $

Comment: Because $4i$ is the other root.  I don't know where $\alpha$ comes from, or why you think it refers to the root you get by taking the plus sign.

Comment: What's bothering me is that if you start from $ i=\frac{-\lambda + \sqrt{\lambda^2+16}}{2}$ and solve for $\lambda$, you get $\lambda=-5i$. But if you substitute that very value of $\lambda$ back in to the equation, you get $i=4i$

Comment: @TookieWookie: Sorry if this doesn't address your specific confusion, but the simplest way to solve this is as follows: if $i$ is a root of the quadratic $z^2+\lambda z-4$, then
$$
i^2+\lambda i-4=0\iff \lambda=-5i \, .
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each non-zero real or complex number $w$ has exactly two square roots $r_1, r_2$ which differ by sign ($r_2 = - r_1$). If $w$ is a *positive real number*, then both $r_1, r_2$ are real and the standard convention is to write $\sqrt w$ for the *positive square root*. In all other cases there is no universally accepted interpretation of $\sqrt w$. If $w$ is a negative real number, then one may of course use the definition $\sqrt w = i \sqrt {\lvert w \rvert}$ (as you do in your calculation). This is a good and reasonable choice for $\sqrt w$, but it is only one of two possible choices. For $w \notin \mathbb R$ it is even more arbitrary to define a unique value of $\sqrt w$.

You corrrectly state that the quadratic equation
$$z^2 + \lambda z - 4 = 0 \tag{1}$$
has the two solutions
$$z=\frac{-\lambda \pm \sqrt{\lambda^2+16}}{2} \tag{2}$$
As explained above, this formula is based on a specific interpretation of the expression $\sqrt{\lambda^2+16}$; it involves a *convention* concerning the symbol $\sqrt{\phantom x }$. Perhaps it would be a more neutral way to say that the solutions of $(1)$ have the form
$$z=\frac{-\lambda + r}{2} \tag{3}$$
where $r$ is any square root of $\lambda^2+16$, i.e. any solution of
$$r^2 = \lambda^2+16 . \tag{4}$$

If you want to have $i$ as a solution of $(1)$, you have to determine $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ and $r$ with $r^2 = \lambda^2+16$ such that
$$i=\frac{-\lambda + r}{2} \tag{5}$$
You write right from the start $r =  \sqrt{\lambda^2+16}$, but this is *inadequate* if you use a fixed convention for the symbol $\sqrt{\phantom x }$. In fact, you must be aware that only one of the two solutions of $(4)$ will satisfy $(5)$ and the other produces a value $ \ne i$. Can you be sure that a fixed square root convention produces the appropriate value for $r$? No, you can't.

Your calculation correctly gives $\lambda = -5i$ and thus $\lambda^2+16 = -9$. The above convention for square roots of negative real numbers produces then $r =  \sqrt{-9} = 3i$ which does not satisfy $(5)$. The other solution of $(4)$ is $r = -3i$ and this is the adequate one which satisfies $(5)$.

**Update:**

A simpler approach is this. You want to find $\lambda$ such that $i$ is a root of $(1)$. Let $\rho$ be the second root of $(1)$. Then
$$(z-i)(z-\rho) = z^2 + \lambda z  - 4$$
which gives $i\rho = -4$ and $-(i + \rho) = \lambda$. The first equation implies $\rho = 4i$ and the second implies then $\lambda = -5i$.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now... except for the bit after "Update: " How do you go from $(z-i)(z-\rho) = z^2 + \lambda z  - 4$  to $i\rho = -4$ and $-(i + \rho) = \lambda$?

Comment: @TookieWookie We have $(z-i)(z-\rho) = z^2 - (i +\rho)z + i \rho$. Now compare the coefficients. Recall Vieta's formulas for quadratic equations!

Answer (score 1):

If a quadratic equation is given with certain coefficients its roots can be found. Else if the roots are given we can find out the quadratic equation that contains/defines these roots.

The only quadratic equation which has roots $\pm \alpha = \pm i\;$
is:
$$ z^2+1=0\text { or } z^2+\alpha^2=0$$

where the complex conjugate *has to be* included.

It is not clear how  the given equation can be imagined or thought of to be able to accommodate these roots. To me appears such adjustment is not possible.

Comment: If we want both $\pm i$ to be roots, your argument is correct. But the OP only requires that $i$ is a root.

Comment: A quadratic equation with real coefficients can have a single isolated stand alone imaginary root? The totality needs to be considered in an answer even if OP asks for an impossible scenario ... or so I assume.

Comment: You are right again if the coefficients of the quadratic equation are required to be real. But the OP does not assume this.

Comment: ok thanks, .. your last edit clarifies it well.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't often discussed in textbooks (at least those I've seen) that polynomial and synthetic division also work for complex numbers.  If we already know one of the zeroes of the polynomial $ \  z^2 + \lambda z - 4 \ $ is $ \ i \ \ , $ we may also carry out the calculation

[image]

We must then have $ \ -5 + \lambda·i \ = \ 0 \ \Rightarrow \ \lambda \ = \ \frac{5}{i} \ = \ -5i \ \ . $  The "reduced" polynomial is then $ \ z + (\lambda + i) \ = \ z + [-5i] + i \ = \ z - 4i \ \ , $ confirming that the second zero is $ \ z = 4i \ \   $ and that the quadratic polynomial is $ \ z^2 - 5i·z - 4 \ \ . $

A small extension (which is not difficult to show) of the theorem that a quadratic polynomial with real coefficients has complex conjugate zeroes is that a quadratic polynomial has a real constant term and imaginary linear coefficent if and only if it has two purely imaginary zeroes.